# file_put_contents(./composer.lock): failed to open stream: Permission denied Even after running chown command

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I am getting this error while installing Laravel latest version on ubuntu 18.04

[ErrorException]
file_put_contents(./composer.lock): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I have even run the following command as suggested by someone in response to the same question

sudo chown -R myuser ~/.composer

Still same error any ideas?

Comment: the command you are running will only help if you're running `composer global ...`. What will help if you're just running composer for the current directory is `sudo chown myuser composer.*` (and possibly deleting vendor in case it also has incompatible permissions)

Comment: I am running the command inside the same directory as composer.

Answer (score 1):

**My error was exactly like below after this command: `composer update`.**

> [ErrorException]
> file_put_contents(./composer.lock): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Solved it only adding `sudo` command in `ubuntu`. Full command will be:

**`sudo composer update`**

Comment: Its not advisable to use sudo for composer install. likewise composer update. It similarly gives the packages you installed super privileges' and they could be malicious

Comment: @Malik How do you want to composer install or composer update on ubuntu.

Comment: Simply install composer on ubuntu

Comment: @Malik In my case I could not  able to generate new file on ubuntu without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

How do you run your php? If it starts when you visit page in browser, then user is `www-data` and of course there are no permissions.

I think you should try change group of this file:

```sh
sudo chgrp www-data ./composer.lock
```

But I am wondering why do you write into composer lock file? Are you ok?

Comment: It's not me who is writing to it, it's laravel installer.

Comment: How do you install laravel, then?

Comment: I downloaded laravel from GitHub then I run composer update command from cli

Comment: Probably you should check out https://laravel.com/docs/8.x

Comment: I've always used `laravel new project-name`